# Ext JD MultiSelect Drag and Drop

Tags: extjs

Has anyone worked on Ext JS here, I need help to resolve an issue.

There are two multiselects Component, and I need to drag and drop items from one multiselect to another.

The issue I am facing is: I am able to drag from One MultiSelect(1st) and drop to another MultiSelect(2nd) only when I am dropping over an already existing element in 2nd MultiSelect.

I am not able to drop to 2nd MultiSelect when I try to drop over an empty space.

I tried to look at the code, but didn't found anything. Is this the way the MultiSelect component works in Ext JS.

Comment: Where is the fiddle code?

Comment: What do you mean by fiddle code, I am new to Ext JS, and I can't paste so much of code here, how can you help me?

Comment: @NEERAJGUPTA, if you could create an example showing the issue at https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home, that would help us in debugging the problem.

Comment: Without code, i can only gues - problem with some listener.

Comment: Did you follow this example? https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/examples/classic/multiselect/multiselect-demo.html